# Creating add-ons for IE8/9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ieaddon

I have a task of "porting" Chrome browser extension to Intrenet Explorer add-on. However I have pretty much trouble even at start. In particular it's hard to fine any kind of general guide, start resource for this. Many links found here on SO are dead, or obsolete by now, or provide some pretty generic info on a subject (such as a templete for BHO).

Is there some kind of *the resource* for IE add-on development now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article about this, but in Czech language only. But you can download my demo - [toolbar button](http://events.dajbych.net/demos/ie.addon.main.zip) or [browser helper object](http://events.dajbych.net/demos/ie.addon.dom.zip). You have to create an *ATL Project* and check *IObjectWithSite*. Images in [my article](http://dajbych.net/jak-vytvaret-doplnky-pro-internet-explorer-dil-1) shows this step by step. They are from English Visual Studio. Hope it helps.